# why the error that row names contain missing values occur

Tags: r

My code is like below and I got an error in data.frame(c(b)) : row names contain missing values.

```
col_name<-colnames(portfolio_25)[2:26]
#b<-seq(from = 1, to=25, by=1) no error if I use this line of code instead of the below one
b<-seq(from =0.5, to=3, by =0.1)

names(b)<-col_name

for(i in col_name){
  lm2 = lm(paste0("I(`",i,"`- RF) ~ I(`Mkt-RF` - RF)"), data = Join_table)
  b[i] =  lm2$coefficients[2]
}

plot <- data.frame(c(b))
```

The commented and uncommented codes are basically following the same logic, so I didn't get why this error occur.

Any help pls would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because lengths of 2 sequence are different.

```
length(seq(from =0.5, to=3, by =0.1))
#[1] 26

length(seq(from = 1, to=25, by=1))
#[1] 25
```

So for the first case you have 26 values whereas for the second one you have 25. The length of `col_name` is 25 since.

```
length(2:26)
#[1] 25
```

So to avoid the error you need to reduce the length of first sequence by 1 to make it of same length as `col_name`.